# What does the "fast forward" mission feature in Borderlands 2 do?

Tags: borderlands-2

Can anyone explain what this fast-foward prompt means?

I jumped in on the BNK-3R quest of "Where Angels fear to tread" with friends in co-op before I got to that point in my own game.  When I accepted the quest for "Angels" from Roland it prompted me to fast foward through parts of the mission i already completed.  I said yes but I don't understand what saying "yes" did and if i should say "no" in the future.